# Firestore OR querey for document fields

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to query a document so that any field is equal to some value?

eg:

collection of documents named `chats`. Each document has two fields - `user1` and `user2`. Can I get all the documents where `user1` or `user2` is 2?

`where('field', 'in', ['value1', 'value2'])`  won't work for this because that can only check one field against multiple values. right?

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does **not** support OR queries: [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=de)

However you can fetch all documents in `chats` with `user1 === 2` and a second fetch with all documents with `user2 === 2` and concat the results

```
let combinedChatArray = chatOfUser1Array.concat(chatOfUser2Array);
```